# How to view cached JS files in chrome with windows 10?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, browser-cache, cache-control

I am getting corrupted JS file when I tried to fetch my gzipped js file in my website. How to see cached files in chrome browser.

There is no "Default" folder under "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data" folder.

I am getting issue something same like discussed in https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=161127

Comment: Open chrome://version and you'll see the full path to your profile.

Comment: @wOxxOm Got it. But where could I see my cached js file?

Comment: in a directory named `Cache`

Answer (score 0):

For a quick way to view the cache to inspect or recover a file, I simply used [Chrome Cache View](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/chrome_cache_view.html).  The web page looks a little dated, but the tool has been updated/confirmed working for Windows 10.